# create folder in powershell with previous date

Tags: windows, powershell, date

I need a Powershell script which helps me to create a folder on destination with one previous date.

Currently, I am using the code below. It helps me to create a folder on destination place with current date but I need folder with previous date.

```
$destination = "C:\abc"
```

Testing if the path Exist or not

```
md $destination -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
```

Create a Test folder in destination path (name will be same as Zip file)

```
$folder = $destination + "\" + (get-date -Format yyyyMMdd) + "." 
$folderName = (get-date -Format yyyyMMdd) + "." md $folder
```

Comment: What does this have to do with gmail?

Comment: I'm a little confused. You just want to make a folder with the date in it's name?

Comment: …or have its timestamp be before the current date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line seems to do the trick:

> (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyMMdd")

Found it on [Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/b5dbe9fc-e716-44ca-8f18-36864bcae791/powershell-getdate-minus-one-day)